# Reducing repetition in the inheritance of class methods

Tags: objective-c

I have a basic `Point` wrapper class:

```
@interface Point : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint point;
- (instancetype)initWithPoint:(CGPoint)point;
@end
```

And a `Line` class that's defined by two `Point`s:

```
@interface Line : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) Point startPoint;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Point endPoint;
+ (NSArray *)linesConnectingPoints:(NSArray *)points;
- (instancetype)initWithStartPoint:(Point)startPoint endPoint:(Point)endPoint;
@end
```

`linesConnectingPoints:` is a convenience method to create an array of lines that connect an array of points together (so if you had an array of 4 `Point`s, calling `linesConnectingPoints:` would presumably create an array of 4 `Line`s representing the sides of a quadrilateral).

```
@implementation Line

+ (NSArray *)linesConnectingPoints:(NSArray *)points
{
    NSMutableArray *lines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:points.count];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < points.count - 1; i++)
    {
        lines[i] = [[self alloc] initWithStartPoint:points[i] endPoint:points[i+1];
    }
    // The final line connects the last point and the first point
    lines[i] = [[self alloc] initWithStartPoint:points[i] endPoint:points[0]];
    return lines;
}
...
@end
```

Now I want to create a `Line` subclass, called `ThickLine`, that adds an additional property of line thickness:

```
@interface ThickLine : Line
@property (nonatomic) float thickness;
- (instancetype)initWithStartPoint:(Point)startPoint 
                          endPoint:(Point)endPoint 
                         thickness:(float)thickness;
@end
```

`initWithStartPoint:endPoint:thickness` becomes the designated initializer, like so:

```
// Overriding the superclass' designated initializer
- (instancetype)initWithStartPoint:(Point)startPoint endPoint:(Point)endPoint
{
    return [self initWithStartPoint:startPoint endPoint:endPoint thickness:1];
}

- (instancetype)initWithStartPoint:(Point)startPoint
                          endPoint:(Point)endPoint
                         thickness:(float)thickness
{
    self = [super initWithStartPoint:startPoint endPoint:endPoint];
    if (self)
    {
        _thickness = thickness;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now I can call `NSArray *thickLines = [ThickLine linesConnectingPoints:somePoints];` and I get an array of `ThickLine`s, each of `thickness` equal to 1.

But what if I wanted to specify the thickness? I could write a method `linesConnectingPoints:withThickness:` and stick it in `ThickLine.m` like so:

```
+ (NSArray *)linesConnectingPoints:(NSArray *)points
                     withThickness:(float)thickness
{
    NSMutableArray *lines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:points.count];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < points.count - 1; i++)
    {
        lines[i] = [[self alloc] initWithStartPoint:points[i]
                                           endPoint:points[i+1]
                                          thickness:thickness;
    }
    lines[i] = [[self alloc] initWithStartPoint:points[i]
                                       endPoint:points[0]
                                      thickness:thickness];
    return lines;
}
```

But this looks exactly like the superclass' `lineConnectingPoints:` method which I already wrote, with the exception of a different initializer being used.

Sure, the repetition here is minimal and isn't such a big deal, but what if I wanted to make multiple other subclasses of `Line`? I could have `ColoredLine`, `LabeledLine`, `FancyLine`, etc. etc., and I'd have to rewrite this "convenience method" for every single subclass (`linesConnectingPoints:withColor:` for `ColoredLine`, `linesConnectingPoints:withText:` for `LabeledLine`, `linesConnectingPoints:withStyle:` for `FancyLine`, etc.). And each convenience method would be exactly the same as the superclass' original, with the exception of more arguments being used in the initializers.

Is there some way to cut down on the repetition here? Some way to encapsulate the repeated code in a separate function, and being able to specify the initializer used?

Answer (score 0):

How about like this?

Line:

```
typedef Line *(^LineFactoryBlock_t)(Point *startPoint, Point *endPoint);

@implementation Line
+(NSArray *)linesConnectingPoints:(NSArray *)points {
    return [self linesConnectingPoints:points withFactoryBlock:^Line *(Point *startPoint, Point *endPoint) {
        return [[self alloc] initWithStartPoint:startPoint endPoint:endPoint];
    }];
}

+(NSArray *)linesConnectingPoints:(NSArray *)points withFactoryBlock:(LineFactoryBlock_t)factory {
    NSMutableArray *lines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:points.count];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < points.count - 1; i++) {
        lines[i] = factory(points[i], points[i+1]);
    }
    // The final line connects the last point and the first point
    lines[i] = factory(points[i], points[0]);
    return lines;
}
//...
@end
```

ThickLine:

```
+(NSArray *)linesConnectingPoints:(NSArray *)points withThickness:(float)thickness {
    return [self linesConnectingPoints:points withFactoryBlock:^Line *(Point *startPoint, Point *endPoint) {
        return [[self alloc] initWithStartPoint:startPoint endPoint:endPoint thickness:thickness];
    }];
};
```